# How to get data for just two hour from previous day,

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-date-functions

I need to get data from previous day (sql server db) for transferring to other DB (postgress), but since data is huge I want to transfer records for just 2 hr, I mean I will run this job 12 times a day and each time it will transfer rec for 2 hr, record transfered should not be duplicate.

So basically I need a query which I can schedule to run 12 times and which will transfer records for two hours each.

Comment: Please FORMAT your question, give details about databases and table structures.

Comment: See [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function: `DATEADD(hour, 2, @date)`.

Comment: I have used dateadd funct..See my requirement is suppose i have 12000 rec for prev day so now my query should run such that first query picks data for 12 AM to 2 AM (yesterday) second query should pick data for 2 AM to 4 AM (yesterday) like this .My col which stored date data is of type DATETYPE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @StartHour datetime, @EndHour datetime

set @EndHour = dateadd(hh,datediff(hh,0,GetDate()),0)
set @StartHour = dateadd(hh,-2,@EndHour)

--The above make the query work with start and end on-the-hour
--so it can be run any time within one hour to get the data
--for the two hours ending on the previous hour

select * from whatever where TheDate between @StartHour and @EndHour
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are timestamping inserts, then it should be simple to run a select to pull out only the preceding two hours worth of records.

```
SELECT * FROM tblFoo WHERE tblFoo.insertionDate>DATEADD(hour,-2,GETDATE())
```

(If you want to be exact, then don't use GETDATE but hold the last date that ran in a table or variable somewhere and add two hours to it each time then setting it after running the query)